# Creating an add-on for an existing plugin

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

I'd like to create a Geofire plugin which extends the current `firebase_database` plugin.
I added the `firebase_database` plugin to the example project in my plugin project and it all works fine. But now I'm trying to actually use the native firebase database library in my plugin project but I can't seem to import it.
So do I have to natively import the firebase database project in my plugin project? Because if so, wouldn't that interfere with the `firebase_database` plugin?

So as an example of what I'd like to import:
I'd like to import `https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_database/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabasePlugin.java`. This is imported in the source code of the `firebase_database` plugin as you can see here: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_database/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabasePlugin.java
This plugin is added to the example project of my plugin project and works fine in the Dart code. Shouldn't I now be able to access that import in my plugin project (so not the example project)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not need to import `FirebaseDatabasePlugin` in your plugin. There are no public APIs of the Java FirebaseDatabasePlugin class for you to call. Instead, you can import the Firebase native classes directly, and add a dependency on the Firebase libraries in the `build.gradle` of your plugin. Just use the same `build.gradle` values that the `firebase_database` plugin does.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. It makes sense that I had to import it natively again when you think about it! But I still have to add the plugin to my example project to test out my plugin ofcourse :)